# commited git folder disappear after checkout

Tags: git

I tried to create a new folder under a local git repository like the following.

1. create a test file name /test/test.txt , under branch "test0"
2. git status shows it is untracked.
3. git add /test/test.txt,
4. git status shows it is Changes to be committed.
5. git commit -m "test"
6. now I try to create a new branch, using git branch test1
7. git checkout test1, now I can not see this test.txt file and the folder.
8. git checkout test0, go back to origi branch, but the folder and file test.txt also disappeared (not able to be seen by ls command)

ps. if I use git rm , I could delete this file. I can use git reset HEAD , then git checkout test.txt, then put this file back.

Do you know which step I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, the folder is not visible with a `ls` command inside your repositorys directory, and a file manager does not show it? But it was visible when you first commited it, i.e. between steps 5 and 6?

Comment: yes, it was there after commit, before I checkout to another branch. Then it disappeared after checkout.

Comment: Did you create another branch or just change your current branch to an existing one? If you commited your file and checked out another existing branch, it won't contain the file since the commit that added it is not part of its history.

Comment: create another and checkout to it, when I mean disappear, I mean those file can not be seen by ls after I checkout back to original branch.